# AWS event to catch RDS IP address change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

IP address of RDS instance can change due to various reasons as mentioned at the bottom of [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-ip-address-issues/) AWS knowledge center page.

I want to get notified or take some action whenever the IP address changes.

Is there a suitable RDS event which can detect this change?
(I referred [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-cloudwatch-events.sample.html) doc page but couldn't find any.)

Comment: Why do you care when the IP address changes? What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: Amazon doesn't recommend using the RDS IP addresses for anything due to the fact the IP address can change. You should be using the DNS name provided by AWS for this. That said, if you feel you have a reason for needing to track this change, more context would be helpful in assisting solving your need.

Comment: The RDS databases are not directly accessible from developers' machine network. So what we do is we've a load balancer having target groups as listeners; & these target groups forward the traffic to RDS' IP address. Thus when the RDS IP address changes, target group becomes invalid and hence developers can not connect to RDS.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you will need to publish all the rds events to an sns topic which will then trigger a lambda function. The lambda function will take  care of the notifications.